# Failing to import external jar containing bean

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot

I'm a little new t working with Spring so any help provided would be great.

I have a SpringApplication class (annotated with @SpringBootApplication. In another class (within the same project), it contains a ServiceClass class. When the class is in the same project, it runs as expected.

When the ServiceClass is moved to an external jar, I get the following error.

> Description:
>
> Field **service** in
> package-to-class.Comp required a
> bean of type 'package-to-class.ServiceClass'
> that could not be found.
>
> The injection point has the following annotations:
>
> - @org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired(required=true)
>
> Action:
>
> Consider defining a bean of type
> 'package-to-class.ServiceClass' in your
> configuration.

I am trying to find what I need to do to inject (@AutoWired) into my project with the above error.

Answer (score 1):

By default, Spring Boot's component scanning [only looks in the same package](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/htmlsingle/#using.structuring-your-code.locating-the-main-class) as the `@SpringBootApplication` and its descendants.

The approach I would suggest is using [`@Import`](https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/context/annotation/Import.html) to import specific beans from outside the project, or use [`@ComponentScan`](https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/context/annotation/ComponentScan.html) to import all beans from a package in another project.

```java
@SpringBootApplication
@Import(ServiceClass.class)
public class SpringApplication {
    // ...
}
```

or

```java
@SpringBootApplication
@ComponentScan(basePackages = "com.example.mylibrary")
public class SpringApplication {
    // ...
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Okey some basic things, you have mixed up your packages a bit.

`@SpringBootApplication` will scan all classes in packages below the class this is annotated on. This annotation is an alias for `@EnableAutoConfiguration`, `@Configuration` and `@ComponentScan` means that `@ComponentScan(basePackages = {"com.springdi.example"}, basePackageClasses = DependencyBasePackageClass.class)` is **not needed**.

```
com.springdi.example     // class with @SpringBootApplication annotation
         |
         |
         |
com.springdi.example.*    // Will find all @Service, @Component, @Configuration
                          // in subpackages below the @SpringBootApplication 
                          // annotation
```

You can read more about the annotation here [SpringBootApplication](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/htmlsingle/#using-boot-using-springbootapplication-annotation)

Since your other annotated classes are **NOT** in the same package structure as the `@SpringBootApplication` you need to define all the places you want to scan for annotations.

```
@SpringBootApplication(scanBasePackages = {"com.springdi.example", "com.dependency.example"})
```

will probably include all the packages that you want to scan through.